# Regex pattern removal in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector with a list of lists for each observation:

```
"Alcohol Dependence (F10.20),Hep B (Z22.51),Hep C (Z22.52),Opioid Abuse (F11.19),Pain- Back, low (M54.5),Pain- Back, upper (M54.9),Respiratory- Tuberculosis (TB) (A15.9)"
```

I am trying to remove the parentheses and everything in between, but I can't figure out the regex expression to use here. I am using the `stringr` package, and `str_replace_all` function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want an output like this:  `"Alcohol Dependence,Hep B,Hep C,Opioid Abuse,Pain- Back, low,Pain- Back, upper,Respiratory- Tuberculosis"`?

Comment: There is a `stringr` answer in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This does *exactly* what is requested - it removes the parentheses and everything in between

```
str_replace_all(text_line, "\\([^\\)]*\\)", "")
```

You might also wish to remove the space(s) before the parantheses start:

```
str_replace_all(text_line, " *\\([^\\)]*\\)", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression:

```
\s*\(.*?\)\s*
```

And replace with an empty string `""`.

```
str_replace_all(your_string, "\\s*\\(.*?\\)\\s*", "")
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EATR7A/2)

Explanation:

- The middle part `\(.*?\)` uses a lazy quantifier (`*?`) so it will stop as soon as a `)` is matched. The `\\s*` at the start and end matches the spaces so you don't get extra spaces in the result.

Comment: Thanks for this, and the explanation... this is amazingly helpful!